# How to call a method by BOTH a button AND a key shortcut

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, actions

I have been trying to call a method by BOTH a key shortcut (as described here http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/snippets.html) and a button I created on the toolbar.

The button works but when I add the code for the shortcut, nothing happens.

```
def initGui(self):
  # Code for the button
  self.my_action = QAction(QIcon(":/path/to/the/icon.png"), u"toolName", self.iface.mainWindow())
  self.my_action.triggered.connect(self.myFunction)
  self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.my_action)

  # Code for the shortcut
  self.iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.my_action, "Ctrl+1")
  QObject.connect(self.my_action, SIGNAL("triggered()"),self.myFunction)

def unload(self):
  # Unload the button
  self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.my_action)

  # Unload the shortcut
  self.iface.unregisterMainWindowAction(self.my_action)

def myFunction(self):
  doSomething
```

Can anybody tell me where (and how) to put the code explained in the link?

Thanks,

m.

**EDIT#1**

I don't know about my system (if other shortcuts work, I don't see why those set on my tools shouldn't) and as far as my code it is pretty straightforward: in the **initGui** method I set up the buttons (what I shared is a "place holder" for the real path of the icons. However, I can see them on both the toolbar and the settings form and everything works fine when clicking the buttons) add them to the toolbar; the **unload** method, unloads them (see the code above **WITHOUT** the redundant signal/slot connection as dakcarto pointed out in the comment); the **run** method sets up the environment (it points at the table -- I am editing a PostGIS table -- and starts an editing session + some tuning)

```
def run(self):
    try:
        # Reference to the layer
        active_layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        # If vector type load a qml file from plugin dir
        if active_layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
              dirPlug = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
              active_layer.loadNamedStyle(dirPlug+"\\file.qml")
        # Start editing session
        active_layer.startEditing()
        # Set CRS and zoom to extent
        canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        canvas.mapRenderer().setProjectionsEnabled(True)
        canvas.mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857))
        canvas.setExtent(active_layer.extent())
        # Refresh          
        canvas.refresh()
        self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(active_layer)
    except:
        QMessageBox.warning(self.iface.mainWindow(),'WARNING','Please, make sure to select a valid shapefile in the TOC')
```

Then I have four buttons calling four identical methods that change values in three different fields of selected features (they differ from each other only for the values they are writing into the DB). Everything works fine when using buttons! I just can't connect a shortcut to them! One of these methods:

```
def oneOfThem(self):
    try:
        # Reference to the layer
        active_layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        # selected features
        sel = active_layer.selectedFeatures()
        # datetime now
        now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S")
        # username
        user = getpass.getuser()
        # if something is selected
        if sel:
            # Change values for selected features
            for s in sel:
                selID = s.id()
                selUser = s.fieldNameIndex('user_lbl')
                selRat = s.fieldNameIndex('rating')
                selTime = s.fieldNameIndex('tile_done_')

                active_layer.changeAttributeValue(selID, selUser, user)
                active_layer.changeAttributeValue(selID, selRat, 1)
                active_layer.changeAttributeValue(selID, selTime, now)

            self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info","Message.", QgsMessageBar.INFO, 3)
        else:
            self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("WARNING","No features selected", QgsMessageBar.WARNING, 3)
    except:
        QMessageBox.warning(self.iface.mainWindow(),'WARNING','Please, make sure to select a valid shapefile in the TOC')
```

That's pretty much it! I didn't touch the **_*init*_** method and I only added my code to the one coming from the **Plugin Builder** Plugin.

m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redundant signal/slot connection:

```
def initGui(self):
  # Code for the button
  self.my_action = QAction(QIcon(":/path/to/the/icon.png"), u"toolName", self.iface.mainWindow())
  # Code for the shortcut
  self.iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.my_action, "Ctrl+1")
  self.my_action.triggered.connect(self.myFunction)  # only need this new-style connection
  self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.my_action)

  # duplicate old-style connection
  # QObject.connect(self.my_action, SIGNAL("triggered()"),self.myFunction)
```

See if removing the duplicate helps. Also, try a different, unique key sequence in case there is a conflict with the "Ctrl+1" sequence.

Also, check *Settings -> Configure shortcuts* dialog to see if your registered QAction and key sequence are showing up.

Comment: Thanks @dakcarto! I check this page for finding conflicts [Features at a Glance](https://qgis-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/features_at_a_glance.html#label-toolbars) and, yes, _Settings->Configure shortcuts_ shows the registered QAction with the associated key sequence but it still not working (is that possible? The tool works when clicking the icon on the toolbar and the chosen key sequence doesn't seem to conflict with any other sequence)

Comment: Hmm. I don't have any issue here using this code. Shortcut just works for me. Try editing an existing plugin (one without a shortcut), and add a shortcut to it. Then see if it functions correctly. If not, try overriding the shortcut in _Configure shortcuts_ and see if the new shortcut works. What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Adding a shortcut to an existing plugin works but overriding the shortcut of mine from _Settings_ did not! I'm using _Valmiera (2.2.0)_. I honestly don't know what's wrong with the code. What else could cause this malfunction?

Comment: Other than something installed on your system that is interrupting shortcuts, I can only surmise that your plugin code has some other issue not displayed here. Can you share the plugin code? Maybe as a link in a comment. Also, is the icon's resource path really ':/path/to/the/icon.png', or is that just sample code?

Comment: Please, see **EDIT#1** above

Comment: I finally had the time to get back on this issue and I realized that assigning from _Configure shortcuts.._ a shortcut TO EACH method (I was working only on one method for testing) did the trick! Probably because they all belong to the same plugin? I have no idea but @dakarto 's answer regarding a **redundant signal/slot** was definitely the right one and I will accept it! Thanks!