# Menu Bug in QGIS Plugin Development

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, development

I'm trying to teach myself to make my first QGIS plugin. I used the Plugin Builder to create the base python files, and the plugin seems to work fine when I press the toolbar icon. I'm now trying to allow the user to use a keyboard shortcut to trigger the plugin as if they were pressing the "ok" button in the plugin dialog - assuming the plugin dialog is already open.  I've done something wrong and now my menu item is repeated in more than one place and I can't remove them:[image][image]

I had trouble getting the [method described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88719/how-to-call-a-method-by-both-a-button-and-a-key-shortcut) to work, and only later realized I wasn't unloading correctly, or at all.

My plugin loading in the initGui is certainly wrong, but so is my
current unload wrong:

```
def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&Copy Attributes'),
            action)
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&Please Copy the Attributes'),
            action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
    # remove the toolbar
    del self.toolbar
    self.iface.unregisterMainWindowAction(self.keyAction)
```

I've used the **Settings -> Configure Shortcuts** manager to remove shortcuts, but I have multiple entries there as well. I originally tried to create a shortcut for the plugin by just using the Shortcut Manager, but it didn't work, so that's why I started trying to do it in the initGui.

I'm not sure of the correct method to unload a menu or toolbar item, but will ask this in a different question.

**Update:** I've managed to figure out how to remove the duplicate menu items. I simply restarted QGIS without the plugin loaded. Then reloaded it from the Plugin Manager. The duplicate menu entries have now disappeared.

Comment: Hi Jan, you can answer your own question (about properly unloading the plugin). This way it will serve as reference for other people with the same problems. Then please open a new question with the other problem (to stay in line with the philosophy of 1 question each).