# How to change visibility when button is clicked again in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to create button that change visibility of grouped layers. When person click button all layers inside group is hidden when is clicked again all layers are visible.

So far i know how to hide layers and set them visible in two separate buttons. But i cannot add to function inside one button.

```
     #connect to Hide_int button that hide intensity rasters
     self.dockwidget.Hide_int.clicked.connect(self.hideint)

     #connect to Hide_img button that hide img rasters
     self.dockwidget.Hide_img.clicked.connect(self.hideimg)                

    def hideint(self):          
        self.maps_treeview = QTreeView()            
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('Int').setVisible(0)            
        print "Connected"            
        pass

    def hideimg(self):            
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('Int').setVisible(2)
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('Int').updateChildVisibility()
        print "Connected"            
        pass
```

I am using Qgis 2.16. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like the following which checks:

- If the group is either unchecked or partially checked then check it
- If the group is checked, uncheck it

Here is the code tested in QGIS 2.18.2:

```
def show_hide_group(self):
    group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('Int')
    # 0 = Unchecked; 1 = Partially checked; 2 = Checked
    if group.isVisible() in (0, 1):
        group.setVisible(2)
    else:
        group.setVisible(0)

self.dockwidget.show_hide_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_hide_group)
```

Answer (score 4):

You might find a toggle button handy. See this [simple plugin](https://github.com/gacarrillor/NewLayersToTheTop/blob/master/newLayersToTheTop.py) for an example.

```
icon = QIcon()
icon.addFile( ":/plugins/myPlugin/iconOff.png", state=QIcon.Off )
icon.addFile( ":/plugins/myPlugin/iconOn.png", state=QIcon.On )
self.action = QAction( icon, u"Toggle group visibility", self.iface.mainWindow() )
self.action.toggled.connect( self.run )
self.action.setCheckable( True )
```

Now, if the button is checked do something, if it's unchecked do something else.

```
def run( self, checked ):
    if checked:
        # Hide the group    
    else:
        # Show the group
```

---

If you used the Plugin Builder, you can achieve it by setting `checkable=True` for the action. See [How to check if plugin icon is toggled?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227578/how-to-check-if-plugin-icon-is-toggled)

How to set shortcuts has been already answered in GIS.SE. For instance: [How to enable a keyboard shortcut for a plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206482/how-to-enable-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-plugin)

Comment: +1, I just implemented the change of the png image file when the icon is toggled. Couldn't find any other example of this anywhere so thanks for including that in your answer :)